# Can I move the favorite icon to the left in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: toolbar, internet-explorer-9

In Internet Explorer 9, the favorite icon is located to the right of the toolbar.

Can I move the icon to the left of the toolbar?

Comment: It's always so sad seeing so many views on an Explorer related question.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found the answer: you can't!

> Currently there isn’t a way to move
>   the Favorites button to the left side
>   of the screen.
>
> ...
>
> ---
>
> Steven  Microsoft Answers Support Engineer

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/im-left-handed-just-upgraded-to-ie9-how-do-i-move/a867fbb9-7516-46da-bc71-027170a4d037

Answer (score 1):

I was unhappy with favourites on the right. A tip on the web was to open the favourites toolbar. Then open "organise favourites" and create a new folder in the favourites bar folder. In my case I named it FAV. Drag all your favourites into the new folder. I deleted all the other unwanted items on the favourites bar leaving only FAV showing.

The great thing is that as I have favorites organised in folders and sub folders, they open from the left across the screen in a clear and logical fashion.

The IE9 screen remains clean and uncluttered with just FAV on the favourites toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't move the icon, you can get the menu bar (With Favorites)  back up on the left of the screen.
Right click on the TOOLS icon and select MENU BAR.

Answer (score 1):

Folow these steps:

1. Right click on the tool bar;
2. Check the menu bar;
3. The menu bar comes up on the left side with favorites on it;
4. Click on Favorites and it comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix.

- Open the browser and go to some random page – Select favorites on the right and select “add to favorites”
- Under the “create in” dropdown list select the ”favorites bar” folder and select “make new folder”. Call the new folder “Fav” for example.
- You will now have a “Fav” Icon on the left side of the browser.
- Close the browser and open Windows Explorer – Go to your profile and find your “Favorites” folder.
- Move all of your favorites and your favorites subfolders to the new folder you created in the browser. The Fav folder you created will be at  `C:\Users\yourname\Favorites\Favorites Bar\Fav`

You must create the Fav folder with IE or you will not be able to add to it. It actually creates the folder in a hidden system folder called links.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> = the old favorites on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Place your cursor at the blue area near the top of the page

Right click, then place a tick beside the top item (called Menu Bar)

Six words appear on the LHS of the screeen in small type one of which is favourites

It isnt a star shaped icon but it does much the same job

I'd like a homepage icon on the LHS too but cant make that happen. So I have saved my homepage as one of my favourites instead and put it at the top for easyish access.

Send Microsoft some pointed feedback saying how awful it is that there is no LHS option for the star icon.  Maybe they will get the message.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and press the <kbd>A</kbd> key. It's not the same as IE8, but it is on left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked your suggestion so I thought I would let you know you can do something to make it work even better.

I came up with this about a year ago because I use the favorites bar to display my favorites sub folders like "News" "Finance" "Shopping" etc... and wanted the folders in my favorites kept in sync with my favorites bar. I.E. when I added a new favorite to "C:\users\%username%\Favorites\News" I also wanted the new site to be added to".\Favorites Bar\News" that way both locations are always the same.

With the solution you added every time you add a new favorite you have to also add it to favorites bar\FAV\ or they do not stay in sync.

You can keep them in sync by instead of copying the contents of your favorites to the favorites bar you create a SYMBOLIC LINK to do this:

1. Open an elevated cmd prompt. (click the Start button, under search type `cmd`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Type: `mklink /d C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Links\Favorites C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites`
   (note that "C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Links" is the actual path of the favorites bar)
3. Go to Internet Explorer and check it out!

Personally I make a batch file, here is how my batch file looks:

```
mklink /d C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Links\News C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\News
mklink /d C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Links\Downloads C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Downloads
mklink /d C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Links\Finance C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Finance
mklink /d C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Links\Reviews C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Reviews
mklink /d C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Links\Shopping C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Shopping
mklink /d C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Links\Misc C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Misc
mklink /d C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites\Links\Favorites C:\Users\%UserName%\Favorites
```